# ASP.NET MVC: generating action link with custom html in it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, actionlink

How can I generate action link with custom html inside.
Like following:
`<a href="http://blah-blah/.....">

    <span class="icon"/>
New customer

</a>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the UrlHelper class :

```
<a href="<% =Url.Action("Create","Customers") %>">
    <span class="icon"/> New customer
</a>
```

The MSDN link is here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx

Comment: o, it is much obvious, that I thought :)  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I've found some helpful info here: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx  and here  http://iridescence.no/post/Rendering-Action-Links-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of .net,

replace

```
 href="<% =Url.Action("Create","Customers") %>"
```

with

```
href="@Url.Action("Create","Customers")"
```

to give something like

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create","Customers")">
   <span class="icon"/> New customer 
</a>
```